# Matrix multiplication of two matrices of sizes 4*2 and 2*4

Tags: c++

I am trying to write the code of Matrix multiplication of two matrices of sizes 4*2 and 2*4. Assume the matrices are A and B. 
My trial for the multiplication part is as follows :

```
int multi_res[4][4];

    for(int i =0 ; i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j<4;j++){
            multi_res[i][j]=0;
            for(int k =0 ;k<4;k++){

            multi_res[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[j][k];
            }

        }



    }
```

However, this code doesn't work for my problem [gives wrong result].

Comment: "does not work" is a pretty generic description of what's going on. Does it not compile? Does it compile, but throws an error? Does it run, but produces wrong results? Please clarify.

Comment: How exactly does it "not work" and how exactly did you try to make it work, and what happened?

Comment: Compare your code with the pseudocode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm). One glaring problem is that since all of the loop bounds are `4`, you're reading `A` and `B` out of bounds.

Comment: please see the edited post

Comment: You're going out of bounds, so you're lucky if giving the wrong result is the worst it does.

Comment: @Beta why out of bounds ?  the  multiplication matrix will be 4x4 ?

Comment: `A` is a 4x2 matrix. What happens when `i == 3` and `k == 3` and you're accessing `A[3][3]`? Likewise for `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop is wrong. It should be

```
for(int k =0 ;k<2;k++){
    multi_res[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
}
```

Assuming that the row is the first index in your array.